# Let my viewcontroller know when a property changes on class being used as a subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like a way for my viewcontroller which has a subview in it, which is it's own class, to find out when a property in this class changes. How do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KVO - key value observation. [See the documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/KVO.html)

KVO is really neat when you have some central data that can be modified in various places and might have different views that need to refresh when a value updates. It's probably perfect for your requirements. The documentation is comprehensive and has lots of examples.

EXAMPLE:

If we want to know when theClass.propertyName changes, we can add an observer like this;

```
[theClass addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"propertyName" options:0 context:nil];
```

Then you need to implement the following method that will receive the notifications when there is a change.

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{   

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString: @"propertyName"]) {
         // Do stuff that you want to do when theClass.propertyName has changed
    }

}
```

DO read the documentation though, it explains it all much better.

Comment: I'd keep upvoting this if I could :) I learned something new today

Comment: I'm still unsure what code to use to set an observer up in my viewcontroller.

Comment: @Andrew, does my extended answer help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
@property ... id *yourProperty;
```

in the **.m** file, you can implement the

```
- (void)setYourProperty:(id)yourProperty;
```

---

**Example:**

```
----

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL highligted;

----

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    // execute some code
}
```

Comment: That's running code inside the class when the value changes, but i'm wondering how to let a viewcontroller know?